# Capture output of command in variable

Tags: bash, script

You know when you do something like `apt-cache search something | less`? Well (in a Bash script) how do you get the input and set it to a variable (like `less` is doing, but `less` isn't a Bash script)?

Comment: So you want to define a variable containing the output of a command in a Bash script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do something like what `less` is doing (receive input on its standard input, process it, then output it) in a script that you write, you can use a `while read` loop in your script.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Beginning"
while read -r line
do
    echo "Processed: [$line]"
done
echo "Ending"
```

Then you can run it like this:

```
some_command | your_script
```

and your output will look like this:

```
Beginning
Processed: [First line of input]
Processed: [Second line of input]
Processed: [Third line of input]
Processed: [Fourth line of input]
Ending
```

Assuming that `some_command` by itself outputs:

```
First line of input
Second line of input
Third line of input
Fourth line of input
```

The variable `$line` is being assigned the value of each line of input in turn. You could accumulate those lines if you needed to by concatenating each line onto a scalar variable:

```
all=$all$line
```

or

```
all+=$line
```

or by appending elements on the end of an array:

```
array+=($line)
```

Answer (score 3):

You are misunderstanding `command | less`. In that scenario, the `less` command doesn't cause the connection; the pipe connects the previous command to `less`. Also, you're saying 'input' where I think you mean 'output'. What you type into the terminal is the input in this case; the output is whatever `command` spits back out. `less` *receives* the output of the command via `|` (aka, the pipe). The pipe takes the standard output of one command and plugs it in as the standard input of another. (You might find [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipe_(Unix)) helpful as a start.)

To assign the output of one command to a variable, you would normally do something like this:

```
variable=$(command)
# older syntax for above
variable=`command`
```

But I very much doubt you really want to assign the output of `apt-cache search foo` to a variable.

Can you elaborate a bit on your larger goal? What are you really trying to do?